# My query won't work when I add a date range to it. Using php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have multiple search fields within one form which the user can pick and choose which one to filter, everything works perfectly until I add the date range to it. If I add the date range alone without any other fields to filter it works so I know it is not that I am writing the query wrong. Please help me figure this out. THANKS!

This is the query that works: (Also for some reason doing SELECT * won't work, I have to type the name of all the fields I want to show)

It includes the part of the form that includes the date range.

```
<li class="form-line form-line-column" id="id_29">
    <label class="form-label-top" id="label_29" for="input_30">
        From Date:
    </label>
    <div id="cid_29" class="form-input-wide">
        <input type="text" class="form-textbox validate" id="datepicker" name="from_date" size="10" />
    </div>
</li>
<li class="form-line form-line-column" id="id_29">
    <label class="form-label-top" id="label_29" for="input_8">
        To Date:
    </label>
    <div id="cid_29" class="form-input-wide">
        <input type="text" class="form-textbox validate" id="datepicker2" name="to_date" size="10" />
    </div>
</li> 

<?php
    $sso = $_GET['sso'];
    $assigned_to = $_GET['assigned_to'];
    $case_status = $_GET['case_status'];
    $startdate = $_GET['from_date'];
    $enddate = $_GET['to_date'];
    $subject = $_GET['subject'];

    $sql = ("SELECT 
                id, sso, full_name, case_status, assigned_to, resolution, 
                description, updated, created, additional_notes, subject
            FROM rmstable2
            WHERE 
                sso LIKE '%$sso%' AND
                case_status LIKE '%$case_status%' AND
                assigned_to LIKE '%$assigned_to%' AND
                subject LIKE '%$subject%'");
?>
```

This is the query I want:

```
<?php
    $sql = ("SELECT 
                id, sso, full_name, case_status, assigned_to, resolution, 
                description, updated, created, additional_notes, subject
             FROM rmstable2
             WHERE 
                sso LIKE '%$sso%' AND
                case_status LIKE '%$case_status%' AND
                assigned_to LIKE '%$assigned_to%' AND
                subject LIKE '%$subject%'
                AND created >= '$startdate'
                AND created <= '$enddate'");
?>
```

Comment: What does your generated query look like? Does it run properly directly in the database?

Comment: Can you show format of your `to_date` and `from_date` fields that come from PHP and also type of `created` field?

Comment: Use created BETWEEN '$startdate' and '$enddate' instead of  created >= '$startdate' AND created <= '$enddate'

Comment: Have you tried using BETWEEN?

Comment: @andrewsi yes it runs perfectly without the date range added to the end of the query, it displays in a table, and also when I plug in actual dates it works. I know I could use BETWEEN, I just never worked with date ranges before.

Comment: @favoretti ok Ill add the code for that.

Comment: @Alexandra - so what does the query with the generated `$to_date` and `$from_date` look like? Does that one run in the database?

Comment: This code is so full of holes you **SHOULD NOT** have this published anywhere. Arbitrary user supplied arguments should **never** be pushed directly into a SQL query. [Escape your SQL properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will be in serious trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `BETWEEN` for that and don't forget to wrap the dates with `DATE( )`

```
$sql = ("SELECT id, sso, full_name, case_status, assigned_to, 
                resolution, description, updated, created, 
                additional_notes, subject 
        FROM  rmstable2 
        WHERE sso LIKE '%$sso%' AND 
              case_status LIKE '%$case_status%' AND 
              assigned_to LIKE '%$assigned_to%' AND 
              subject LIKE '%$subject%' AND 
              DATE(created) BETWEEN DATE('$startdate') AND DATE('$enddate')");
```

**UPDATE 1**

how about changing `AND` to `OR`

```
$sql = ("SELECT id, sso, full_name, case_status, assigned_to, 
                resolution, description, updated, created, 
                additional_notes, subject 
        FROM  rmstable2 
        WHERE sso LIKE '%$sso%' OR 
              case_status LIKE '%$case_status%' OR
              assigned_to LIKE '%$assigned_to%' OR 
              subject LIKE '%$subject%' OR
              (DATE(created) BETWEEN DATE('$startdate') AND DATE('$enddate'))");
```

Comment: I tried it, but it only works if I fill ALL the search fields, not if I just fill one and leave the rest empty :/

Comment: yes it is, the format is not the problem, the problem is when filtering with multiple other fields.

Comment: if that's the case, do not use `AND` but instead use `OR`

Comment: for all of them or just for date range?

Comment: see my updated answer, all of them but for the date range use `AND`

Comment: No this made it worse :(  now it just keeps bringing up everything, doesnt filter any field at all

Comment: I think the better solution would be, your `where` clause will be dynamic in the sense that when user enters a value from the inputbox fields, it will then be the basis of your `where` clause, for example, if i fill in `case_status` textfield, the condition will only `WHERE case_status LIKE '%$case_status%'`. I hope it makes sense now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use  `echo $sql;`  and to paste the generated query in phpmyadmin(if u have such)! Other helpful command is `echo mysql_error()`.

In your case most probably you have to check if the date format is right (it should be YYYY-MM-DD)

Also make this 
`AND created >= '$startdate' AND created <= '$enddate'");`

to this
`AND created >= '" . $startdate . "'
             AND created <= '" . $enddate . "'");`

Because if...

```
$a=1;
echo '$a';
```

will output

```
$a
```

Comment: Not all people use `phpmyadmin`, you know ;) I never used anything other than mysql console for that matter and even find phpmyadmin annoyingly inconvenient :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your values are formatted correctly, you could try using DATE(created) in your final query like:

```
AND DATE(created) >= '$startdate' AND DATE(created) <= '$enddate'
```

or even use BETWEEN such as:

```
AND DATE(created) BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming date is like YYYY-MM-DD, or you can explode the time to create an timestamp
// assuming your date field in the database is date
// you can remove FROM_UNIXTIME if your field is not date

$startdate = strtotime($_GET['from_date']);
$enddate = strtotime($_GET['to_date']);


$addQuery = "";

if(isset($startdate)){
     $addQueryStart = "created >= FROM_UNIXTIME($startdate)";
}
if(isset($startdate)){
     $addQueryEnd = "created <= FROM_UNIXTIME($enddate)";
}

if(isset($startdate) && isset($enddate)){
    $addQuery .= "AND (".$addQueryStart." AND ".$addQueryEnd.")";
} elseif(isset($startdate) && !isset($enddate)){
    $addQuery .= "AND ".$addQueryStart;
} elseif(!isset($startdate) && isset($enddate)){
    $addQuery .= "AND ".$addQueryEnd;
}



$sql = "
    SELECT id, sso, full_name, case_status, assigned_to, resolution, description, updated, created, additional_notes, subject 
    FROM rmstable2 
    WHERE 
        sso LIKE '%$sso%' AND 
        case_status LIKE '%$case_status%' AND 
        assigned_to LIKE '%$assigned_to%' AND 
        subject LIKE '%$subject%' ".$addQuery;
```

Later edit: for different situations

Comment: This only works if the date range is filled, if it is left empty nothing shows.

Comment: Yes, it's for your example, if you need to leave some field you can make filters before the query.

Comment: you mean like create a condition?